# How to stop Django from evaluating false template conditions?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a Django template that renders links defined by specific apps like:

```
<div>{% url 'admin:myapp_myview' %}</div>
```

However, I want to make this app optional in my code, so I created a simple tag, called `is_installed`, like:

```
import logging
from django.apps import apps

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@register.simple_tag
def is_installed(name):
    result = apps.is_installed(name)
    logger.info('App "%s" is installed? %s', name, result)
    return result
```

and use that to wrap my link in an if statement like:

```
{% load mytags %}
{% is_installed "myapp" as is_myapp_installed %}
{% if is_myapp_installed %}
    <div>{% url 'admin:myapp_myview' %}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Unfortunately, it looks like regardless of the value of `is_myapp_installed`, Django's template engine evaluates all parts of the template, even if those parts are wrapped in if statements with false conditions.

This means that when I disable `myapp` from my `INSTALLED_APPS` list, I see my log output:

```
App "myapp" is installed? False
```

Yet Django gives me the template error:

```
Reverse for 'myapp_myview' not found. 'myapp_myview' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

implying it's ignoring the if statement.

Is there any way to fix this and stop Django from evaluating code inside false if statements?

Are there alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You need [with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with) template tag like this:

```
{% with "myapp" as myapp %}
  {% if myapp|is_installed %}
    <div>{% url 'admin:myapp_myview' %}</div>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: That produces the same error. Django still evaluates the template code inside the with/if clause even if it doesn't render them.